# ¿Se debe usar proceso o asignación interna?

Tags: algoritmos, diagrama-de-flujo

Para dibujar un diagrama de flujo que incluye una constante (en este caso la gravedad de la tierra es g=9.81 m/s^2) se debe utilizar un rectangulo simple de proceso:

[image: Imagen_proceso]

o el de asignación interna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que irá dentro de la figura es: g=9.81 que es una constante.
No encontré etiqueta para diagrama de flujo, disculpen si está en una categoría diferente.

Comment: Estas usando alguna herramienta especifica o es a hoja y lapiz

Comment: Hola Pedro, estoy usando el freeware Dia.

Comment: Pues a como entiendo debes usar asignación directa ya que la gravedad es una constante @Robby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Proceso**
  <sub>Puesto que no existe un símbolo para definir una constante o una variable, por lo regular se utiliza el primero. Ejemplo:</sub><sup>1</sup>

  [image: set variables]
- **Almacenamiento interno**
  <sub>El segundo se utiliza para ilustrar que la información se encuentra almacenada en la memoria RAM y no en un dispositivo de almacenamiento.</sub><sup>2</sup> <sub>Sin embargo, es poco utilizado. Se sustituye con frecuencia por el primero. Ejemplo:</sub><sup>3</sup>

  [image: flowchart]

<sub>Puede verse una lista con estos y otros símbolos en [*Simbología de Diagramas de Flujo*](http://diagramasdeflujo-edwin.blogspot.mx/).</sub>

<sup>————————————

*Notas*

**1**. *Flowchart Terminology and Examples*, http://spot.pcc.edu/~rchriste/121/flowchart.html

**2**. *Internal Storage - Flowchart Object*, http://creately.com/diagram-type/objects/flowchart/internal-storage-flowchart-object. También *What do the different flowchart shapes mean?*, http://www.rff.com/flowchart_shapes.htm

**3**. *A Simple Calculator*, Prelab Flowchart, https://github.com/byarbrough/ece382_lab01</sup>